# DS18b20 ethernet cable wiring

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sensors

I plan to connect some DS18B20 temperature sensor to a Raspberry Pi.
My point is to avoid capacitance problem and other comunication pitfalls due to cable length.

Distance between sensor and RPi is about 3 to 10 meters.
The area might have electromagnetic disturbances due to presence of AC motors

I suppose that Ethernet CAT5 cable (shielded) is a good choice.
Considering that the cable has 4 twisted pairs, I am wondering what is the best wiring for a sensor:

- VDD, GND, Data each on a different pair?
- VDD and Data on the same pair?
- other?
- It doesn't matter?

Consedering that a portion of the way between the Rpi and some sensors is common, could I use the same cable or is it better to avoid this?

Have you got any other advices about this type of wiring in order to be able to maximize the cable length if needed?

Thanks in advance for you advices

Answer (score 0):

https://www.instructables.com/id/DS18B2O-Temperature-probe-with-RJ45-connector/

```
STANDARD TO BE USED:

1 - RX (+) - Receive Data (+) ---------- WHITE/ORANGE - none
2 - RX (-) - Receive Data (-) ---------- ORANGE ------- YELLOW - DATA
3 - TX (+) - Transmit Data (+) --------- WHITE/GREEN -- none
4 - DC (+) - Power-over-Eithernet (+) -- BLUE --------- RED ---- VCC
5 - DC (+) - Power-over-Eithernet (+) -- WHITE/BLUE --- none
6 - TX (-) - Transmit Data (-) --------- GREEN -------- none
7 - DC (-) - Power-over-Eithernet (-) -- WHITE/BROWN -- none
8 - DC (-) - Power-over-Eithernet (-) -- BROWN -------- BLACK -- GND
```

Comment: I believe you may be answering a different question to what is being asked. The original question is about choosing a type of cable/wiring to minimize issues related to interference and cable length.